# Inject Text inside a paragraph

Tags: php

I have a paragraph like below

```
$content = '<p>Clashes broke out at one refinery on Tuesday when police broke up a blockade in Marseille. Workers at a large oil terminal in the port of Le Havre were due to go on strike on Thursday to block imports.Transport Minister Alain Vidalies said 40% of petrol stations around Paris were struggling to get fuel.Motorists have been panic-buying to avoid shortages.</p>';
```

I would like to inject another text `$added_text = 'Honorable';` before **Transport Minister Alain Vidalies** of this paragraph.

How can I do that using PHP ??

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: This may be help you: `str_replace("Transport Minister Alain Vidalies", "Honorable Transport Minister Alain Vidalies", $str)`

Comment: Thanks @Epodax for your reply. I searched in Google but could not find any suitable solution. I got some `preg_replace()` solution. But I would not like to replace anything. That's why I looking for solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive it using `strpos()` and `substr_replace` as

```
 $content = '<p>Clashes broke out at one refinery on Tuesday when police broke up a blockade in Marseille. Workers at a large oil terminal in the port of Le Havre were due to go on strike on Thursday to block imports.Transport Minister Alain Vidalies said 40% of petrol stations around Paris were struggling to get fuel.Motorists have been panic-buying to avoid shortages.</p>';
$find="Transport Minister Alain Vidalies";
echo $pos=strpos($content, $find);

$added_text = 'Honorable ';

echo $newstr = substr_replace($content,$added_text,$pos, 0);
```

Check **[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/LKWBm)**

Answer (score 0):

You can glue strings to getting using `.`, like this:

```
$content = '<p>Clashes broke out at one refinery on 
Tuesday when police broke up a blockade in Marseille. 
Workers at a large oil terminal in the port of 
Le Havre were due to go on strike on Thursday to 
block imports.'.$added_text.'Transport Minister Alain 
Vidalies said 40% of petrol stations around Paris were
struggling to get fuel.Motorists have been panic-buying 
to avoid shortages.</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks @LinkinTED for your reply. Paragraph is inside a variable. If I `echo` the variable then I got the Paragraph. As a result I could not implement your solution.

Comment: Then you could use the solution Frayne Konok gives in the comments. Or the answer from Saty.